# PHP variable declaration

Tags: php, mysql

I have some simple system to upload files and keep track of them for each particular user, using a database.

The problem of mine is, I connect to the database in the file `checklogin.php`, which is responsible to handle the `$_POST` from `main_login.php`.

In file 'checklogin.php':

```
$current_user_name = NULL;
```

which is a global variable for all files. Now in file `signup.php`, I try to include the `checklogin.php` to define that variable:

```
require_once '/checklogin.php';
...
mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . tbl_name . " (username, userpassword, userisadmin) 
         VALUES (''" . $_POST['myusername'] . "',"
         . "'" . md5($_POST['mypassword']). "',"
         . "0)");
$current_user_name = $_POST['myusername'];
header("location:login_success.php");
```

As you can see, I'm trying to set the value of the variable `$current_user_name = $_POST['myusername'];`, but when `header` goes to the file `login_success.php`, which is having `require_once '/checklogin.php';` too, the variable is set again to `null`.

How can I solve this problem? i.e. How can I store the current user so that it is accessible by all files?

Comment: Why not make `$current_user_name` as a `SESSION` variable instead ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I'm still a begginer in php ...

Comment: Always sanitize your inputs from $_POST or $_GET before creating a query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Comment: You really should never use global variables in PHP. You should use a session variable in order to keep track of things on a per-user basis.

Comment: It seems you do not have a text field named `myusername`make sure you have it e.g `<input type="text" name="myusername" />` otherwise you wouldn't e having a `NULL`

Comment: @meLove I'm doing this check before running the code snippet above: `if (array_key_exists('myusername', $_POST)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store a variable like that. Each request will be new execution in sever. In this kind situation we have to use session please check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

And another issue with your code is SQL injection, Please read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) too

Answer (score 1):

You can not access the Parameter received at checklogin.php

what you can do you can check the the login status and set the current user in session.

From session variable you can access and set the current user.

Answer (score 1):

you can set a session variable for it and on every you can use it like this

```
session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['current_user_name']))
    {
      $current_user_name = $_SESSION['current_user_name'];
    }
    else
    {
      $current_user_name = NULL;
    }
```

and set your session variable as follows

```
session_start();
require_once '/checklogin.php';
////...
mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . tbl_name . " (username, userpassword, userisadmin) 
         VALUES (''" . $_POST['myusername'] . "',"
         . "'" . md5($_POST['mypassword']). "',"
         . "0)");
$current_user_name = $_POST['myusername'];
$_SESSION['current_user_name'] = $current_user_name; // set your session here
header("location:login_success.php");
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I cannot choose more than one best answer !